# Firefox extension to move Unsorted Bookmarks to Bookmarks Menu automatically

Tags: gratis, firefox, bookmark

When you click the star near the URL in Firefox, the current URL is stored as a bookmark in the `Unsorted Bookmarks` folder. Instead, I would like them to be stored directly in the `Bookmarks Menu` for easy access.

Pressing CTRL-D (or clicking `Bookmark This Page` puts the bookmark in `Bookmarks Menu`, but I would like the same for the star.